# MongoDb in Docker Compose - providing a configuration

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Have tried following various guides, articles and SE answers on this but seem to be hitting a brick wall when trying to deploy this to our test server (a CentOS vm running docker, compose etc).

I can get mongo to launch, but it seems to go into localhost only mode with no authentication (even though parameters are supplied), and the setup .js script never seems to run either.

I'd like to try and get this working fully so our continuous integration pipeline is nice and easy to use.  The problem seems to be that the documentation for this is variously out of date, fragmented and otherwise difficult to piece together into a working whole.

**What I've tried:**

Created a JS file with some users set up (MongoSetup.js)

```
use admin

db.createUser({ "user" : "superUserAdmin",
"pwd" : "1234",
"roles" : [
{
"role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
"db" : "admin"
} ]
})

db.createUser({ "user" : "writeUser",
"pwd" : "1234",
"roles" : [
{
"role" : "readWrite",
"db" : "FOO"
} ]
})

use FOO

db.createCollection("logs")
```

The commands in this file have been tested against Mongo CLI and seem to work just fine.

Created a Dockerfile to try to copy this file as part of a build:

```
FROM mongo
COPY MongoSetup.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENTRYPOINT usr/bin/mongod
```

This bit I'm less sure about, but it does seem that the .js file is copied to that directory on the host.

Finally, the Docker-Compose file: (this is an extract, but the file is valid)

```
mongo-logger:
    image: FOOmongo #(the image we created and pushed to our registry using the dockerfile above)
    environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
    command: bash -c 'mongo < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/MongoSetup.js'
    network_mode: "bridge"
    volumes:
    - mongologger:/data/db
    logging:
     driver: syslog
     options:
      syslog-address: "udp://127.0.0.1:514"
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

It seems at the moment that the mongo container starts...then dies after a few seconds, with connection issues in the logs.

**Other stuff I've tried**

Trying to enable Mongo authentication in the compose file:

```
command: mongod -auth --bind_ip all
command: mongod --auth --bind_ip all
```

With the correct IP addresses too instead of all.

Trying to use Bash command from within the Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["bash","/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/MongoSetup.js"]
```

I've tried variously adding and removing these lines in different combinations but to no good effect.  I'm sure there's some rookie mistakes in there somewhere but it's a pretty confusing cocktail - mongo, linux, dockerfile, docker-compose and docker commands.

Can anyone please advise on:

1) How to set mongo to start in a mode where it is remotely accessible.

2) And/or run the script to setup the default users and db.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget the leading `/` in your Dockerfile? ENTRYPOINT usr/bin/mongod

Comment: As in ENTRYPOINT / usr/bin/mongod or ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/mongod? (sorry I'm pretty new to Linux)

Comment: That seems to have helped (/usr/bin/mongod) - the authentication settings are taken.  Thanks for your help...so annoying to get 99.9% of the way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the leading `/` in your Dockerfile. This is the correct line:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/mongod
```